# Breakpoints are not hitting in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, breakpoints

I've been working on an existing Windows Workflow foundation project to improve its performance. The current project uses Windows workflow foundation and has custom activities. The current deployment model is a console application (where methods use `HttpGet`, `HttpPost`, etc to serve requests)  which uses `TopShelf` to run as Windows service. The console app receives the requests, and calls the appropriate activity from the activities project. The console app more or less acts like a web API. I noticed the requests are handled in a poor fashion by the console app. So, I changed the existing console application to a Web API and the performance has increased drastically.

However, there is a twist. After I added a new Web API project, and ported the same code from Console App to Web API, and ran it in **IIS Express**, I am not able to hit breakpoints in the activities project. Here is what I tried already:

1. I tried to match the framework of the projects (activities was using .NET 4.0, now I upgraded it to .NET 4.5.1).
2. I created a brand new workflow activities project, and copied over the code from old activities and placed a break point, and it still did not hit.
3. I checked all the settings in visual studio and followed suggestions from some posts on SO and it didn't work.
4. Upgraded all the packages used by all projects in the solution to the latest (from **Nuget**).
5. The Workflow activities project uses 2 third party *DLLs* which mention the run-time version as 4.0.30319. I am yet to find out if there is an updated version of those *DLLs* from them. Could this be an issue?

I am using VS 2015 as my IDE.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: what's the problem??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you post some example code, you are more likely to get an answer!

Comment: @Asif.Ali I am not able to hit breakpoints in the activities project. This is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check/set multiple options/settings in your VS:

- Enable **"Managed Compatibility Mode"** by going to `Tools -> Options -> Debugging`.
- Make sure you have selected correct platform configuration Debug/Release.
  [image]
- Make sure correct server is selected **IIS Express** / **IIS local** / **External Host** by going to `Project -> Properties... -> Web` and make sure uncheck **Optimize Code** under `Build` tab.
- Uncheck **Only Build startup...** and select **Always Build** under **On Run, when...** drop down by going to `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run`.